# Squirrelmail default page

Tags: linux, apache

I have install squirrelmail, everything is ok. I can log to http//:192.168.20.20/webmail. Now i want to make a change for when someone go to http//:192.168.20.20/ then they redirect to login page of squirrelmail.
I has try to make a redirect or change DirectoryIndex but it not working.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to change the default DocumentRoot directory (ex. /var/www/html/webmail) in the corresponding configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by RoseHosting, the easiest way to do this is to set the `DocumentRoot` to the [SquirrelMail](https://squirrelmail.org/) directory, such as :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webmail
```

You can set this directive in the main server configuration file or in the configuration file of the [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/), if you have created one. Read the  documentation of the [DocumentRoot directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot) for more information.